# What exactly do this TomCat init patameter setting? (trimSpaces setted on true)

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am setting the development environment for a product on which I have to work.

Into the tutorial I found that it say that I have to modify the TomCat **web.xml** configuration file adding these line into the  section:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

What exactly do this setting?

Tnx

Comment: You may need to read [this](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/VIVO/Tomcat+-+configure+JSP+compiler+to+trim+spaces) and [that](http://kualigan.blogspot.com/2012/08/tomcat-jsp-trimspaces-optimization.html) pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is this is a parameter that's nested inside a

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>fork</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

According to a tutorial -

> "If you wish, you can modify Tomcat's settings to reduce the amount of
>   white space in HTML that is created from JSPs (Java Server Pages).
>   White space is controlled by the trimSpaces parameter in the JSP
>   compiler."